# Android Automotive

Tags: android, android-automotive

i have question regarding Android Automotive OS apps. Apart from media and messaging app is there any guidelines and support for developing games for android automotive OS. also Like gaming can we develop any apps focusing other business area like UBER and so ?
does google planned anything near feature and when ?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) will help

Comment: @a_local_nobody thanks for the comment. your link redirects to stack overflow instruction page which doesn't have any relevance for my question.

Answer (score 1):

Google released a new blogpost today about this. Seems that it may become available at some point after the end of this year:

> Today, we’re showcasing our work with early access partners to build
> apps in new categories for Android Auto, including navigation, parking
> and electric vehicle charging. [...] Our early access partners will be
> releasing new apps to their beta testers by the end of this year.
> Pending additional testing and feedback, we then plan to make these
> APIs publicly available for all developers to build Android Auto apps
> in these categories.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/android-for-cars.html

**Update**: The library is now available in Beta: https://developer.android.com/training/cars/navigation

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone knows the answer beyond maybe. To quote this article, https://venturebeat.com/2019/05/01/google-opens-android-automotive-to-app-developers/, where Google discusses opening up Android Automotive to developers:

> Media apps are just the first type the company is soliciting. Google also hints at plans to let developers build apps for navigation (mapping solutions), communication (calls, messages), “and beyond.”